# Error while installing the "base" Office 365 Outlook add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office365-apps

I created an Outlook add-in using Office developer tools for Visual Studio 2015.

The project is correctly generated, and I deployed it to an azure app service.

When I try to add the add the manifest to my Office 365 dev subscription, I get the following error :  "Something went wrong, and we couldn't install your add-in. Please try again later"

This manifest is the exact manifest generated by VS, the only modification was to replace the place holder for the Web URL by the one of the Azure app service.

Has anyone encountered this issue before ?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you add the manifest? Is it helpful to [sideload](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing) the Office add-in? And to deploy the Outlook add-in manifest to Exchange, we need the role "My Custom Apps" at least. Please check [this article](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/testing-and-tips?product=outlook) to see whether it is helpful.

Comment: Are you uploading this via URL? If OWA cannot reach that URL this is often the error that is given.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload or copy/paste the manifest you are trying?

If you are installing via URL. This is also a common error that is given when OWA cannot download the Manifest from the URL. There could be permissions/something wrong with the URL.

Otherwise, you may also get more detailed information on why the install is failing if you install from the Manage App page instead of the In Client Store Page. (Detailed errors on the In Client Store Page will be added soon)

[image]